# Running time of for loop

Tags: performance, big-o

I seem to understand the basic concepts of easier loops like so...the first loop runs in O(n), as does the inner loop. Because they're both nested, you multiply to get a total running time of O(n^2).

```
sum = 0; 
for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
  for j = 0; j < n; j++ ) 
    ++sum;
```

Though when things start getting switched around, I get completely lost as to how to figure it out. Could someone explain to me how to figure out running time for both of the following? Also, any links to easy to understand references that could further help me improve is also appreciated.  Thanks!

```
sum = 0; 
for( i = 0; i < n; i += 2 ) 
  for( j = 0; j < n; j++ ) 
    ++sum;
```

The only thing I can gather from this is that the inner loop runs in O(n). The i+=2 really throws me off in the outer loop.

```
sum = 0; 
for( i = 1; i < n; i *= 2 ) 
  for( j = 0; j < n; j++ ) 
    ++sum;
```

From my attempt...outer loop is O(log(n)), inner is O(n), so total is O(n log(n))?

Comment: Hint: the `+= 2` means it's doing half as many iterations as it would with `++`.

Comment: So this means the outer loop runs in O(n/2)?

Comment: yes the outer loop takes n/2  but remember that we are interested in very large numbers of n,  so just as 2n would become O(n) n/2 would become O(n).

Comment: Oh right! Constants are dropped. So O(n) for outer  and O(n) for inner gives it a total running time of O(n^2), correct?

Answer (score 3):

A good way of thinking about Big-O performance is to pretend each element of the code is a mathematical function that takes in `n` items and returns the number of computations performed on those items.

For example, a single `for` loop like `for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )` would be equivalent to a function `i()`, where `i(n) = n`, indicating that one computation is performed for each input `n`.

If you have two nested loops, then the functional equivalent for

```
for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
   for j = 0; j < n; j++ )
```

would look like these two functions:

```
i(n) = n * j(n)
j(n) = n
```

Working these two functions out produces an end result of `n*n = n^2`, since `j(n)` can be substituted for `n`.

What this means is that as long as you can solve for the Big-O of any single loop, you can then apply those solutions to a group of nested loops.

For example, let's look at your second problem:

```
for( i = 0; i < n; i += 2 ) 
  for( j = 0; j < n; j++ )
```

`i+=2` means that for an input set of `n` items `(n0, n1, n2, n3, n4)` you're only touching every other element of that set. Assuming you initialize so that `i=0`, that means you're only touching the set of `(n0,n2,n4)`. This means you're halving the size of the data set that you're using for processing, and means the functional equivalents work out like:

```
i(n) = (n/2) * j(n)
j(n) = n
```

Solving these gets you `(n/2) * n = (n^2)*(1/2)`. Since this is Big-O work, we remove the constants to produce a Big-O value of `(n^2)`.

The two key points to remember here:

1. Big-O math starts with a set of `n` data elements. If you're trying to determine the Big-O of a `for` loop that iterates through that set of `n` elements, your first step is to look at how the incrementor changes the number of data elements that the `for` routine actually touches.
2. Big-O math is *math.* If you can solve for each `for` expression individually, you can use those solutions to build up into your final answer, just like you can solve for a set of equations with common definitions.

Comment: Thank you. In the last problem I presented, I noticed that the outer loop starts off with i=1 and the inner loop j=0. Would this affect how the running time is determined based off what I said in the original post? I guess what I'm saying is if the outer loop is O(log(n)), would j=0 affect it being O(n)?

Comment: I suspect that the `i=1` is there just to make `i *= 2` make sense (can't constructively multiply by zero).

But, good question. Keep in mind that O() eliminates constants, since we're looking at computation proportional to the size of the dataset. Starting at `n1` means that `i` only works through `n-1` elements of the set... and that `-1` is a constant value.